# Few questions about angular-formly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I am looking for a library for form building based on provided model, so we are looking at formly:)
I took a glance into the examples and video on formly web site, but there are still some questions without
an answer.

-There are a lot of examples of viewing/editing single entity via formly. I am interested in some example of viewing/editing collection of entities via formly (being displayed e.g. as a table). Each field of table should have it's own type.

-Editing single entity is cool. But what if editing one entity requires creation of the other entity. E.g. what if you create "User" entity, and you need to create/choose existing "Bank Account" entity to link with User? What is the best way to do such a thing?

-Are there any examples of client + server applications using formly? (e.g, we get forms from server side?). Maybe, some attributes (annotations) to classes, fields for automatic formly objects generation?

Comment: for this kind of questions you should answer it at: http://stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the things your talking about with formly. If you need help with something specific, follow the instructions at http://help.angular-formly.com

Comment: Thnx, Kent. Indeed, I have managed to create formly form, which renders model data as a table.
Now I am thinking about advantages of what I have made. Creating complex forms with links, popups and etc. requires really HUGE form json.
In fact size of the json is close to size of angular html code, when I'm using angular directives instead.

Comment: What are the advantages of angular-formly over properly written directive?
For now I am thinking that the only serious advantage is the ability to somehow generate large formly forms automatically on server side.

Comment: I recommend you ask that to other users of angular-formly on the chart: http://chat.angular-formly.com